# Got a Error and a Warning when installing 'MIICD' package

Tags: r

My output:

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/User/Downloads/MIICD_2.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
將程式套件安載入 ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(因為 ‘lib’ 沒有被指定)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  安裝程式套件 ‘C:/Users/User/Downloads/MIICD_2.4.tar.gz’ 時退離狀態的值不是 0
```

I know the Error is because of path, but it appeared when I open RStudio.
R version: 4.2.3
System: Windows

I had tried install the `.zip` file, it successed but got this when library it.

```
> library(MIICD)
Error: 套件或命名空間載入失敗 ‘MIICD’:
 package ‘MIICD’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to use the function in this package. Extract the `.tar.gz` file, then you can find those function in `R` folder.
Then, I can use [these](https://gist.github.com/johnatasjmo/f6073976b5e1aac3d755ee1852a3aca5) way to load those function into my environment.

```
setwd("~/rProgramming")
files.sources = list.files()
sapply(files.sources, source)
```